# Line break a string on x number of characters but not through a word

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, line-breaks

I'll try to explain what I am looking for as best as I can. Currently, I am using this code to line break every x number of characters.

```
public static string SpliceText(string text, int lineLength)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(text, "(.{" + lineLength + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

This works great, but often it will break every x number and obviously will sometimes break through a word. Is it possible for code to check if it is breaking mid-word, and if it's not mid-word to break anyways but now check if the first character after the break is a space and remove it if so?

I know I am asking for a lot, but thanks in advance anyways!

Comment: Just so you know, unless you are laying out text in a wholly customized way, all of the controls you are using support text wrapping modes natively.

Comment: Try to give an example of input and output

Comment: @Jay I was under the impression that ListBox cannot Word Wrap.

Comment: @user2416047 It doesn't but you're not putting plain text in your listbox items are you? Usually you put elements, TextBlock, TextBox, etc.. and they all support word wrapping.

Comment: @user2416047 You can define a template for the items in the `ListBox`. They can contain formatted text, images, videos -- anything! See this Visual Studio Mag article: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/04/01/Working-with-ListBoxes-in-a-Windows-Phone-Application.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static string SpliceText(string text, int lineLength)
{
    var charCount = 0;
    var lines = text.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .GroupBy(w => (charCount += w.Length + 1) / lineLength)
                    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g));

    return String.Join("\n", lines.ToArray());
}
```

Here's my screen shot for this:
[image]

Comment: I got a few errors, not sure I should be importing anything.

The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'

The name 'los' does not exist in the current context

And today is the day I realized I don't know how to format this properly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit my test with LINQ Pad. Please check this now. I included my testing screenshot.

Comment: I had to use `ToArray()` on that g lambda variable to get rid of that "best overloaded match" error.  `GroupBy` returns an `IGrouping`, not a string array.